# does anything get executed when i extend from an abstract class?

Tags: java, android

i'm currently reading the 3rd version of bignerdranch android book, i don't have any problem executing the codes , but i really want to know how abstract class works here. i have an activity class that extends from an abstract class to create fragments . most of the job is done in the abstract class and i only override an abstract method in activity class , but i wonder how does onCreate method in abstract method gets executed, shouldn't i call it in activity class??

```
public class CrimeActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {
@Override
public Fragment CreateFragment() {
    return  new CrimeFragment();
```

}

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public  abstract Fragment CreateFragment();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_activity_fragment_container);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if(fragment == null)
    {
        fragment = new CrimeFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of having a `abstract` class  while you are doing all of the stuff in parent class .. In most of the cases we use `abstract` Activity to reuse code ..

Comment: you're right in case we only have one **activity** , but this project in the book have multiple **activity**  and writers of the book consider defining **abstract** class as best practice.

Comment: Abstract class does not allow any implementation. Take `Animal` abstract class, does it make sense to write any implementation of an `Animal`? The animal is an abstract concept with no real meaning unless you extend it and provide the concrete implementation. Like `Dog` extends `Animal`. A dog is an animal but an animal can not necessarily be a dog. While you may write certain class members and write their super implementation and make them open for extension, then on extending them you can invoke their implementation via a `super` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

whenever Android loads an activity, it starts by invoking `onCreate` lifecycle of your activity which in your case is coming from the abstract class
`Abstract` classes abstracts out some functionality which may or may not be used by derived class.
In this case `onCreate` function of abstract class is that abstracted piece, If you want to avoid calling that you can do so by overriding an empty implementation in derived class.

Comment: so only the necessary **non-abstract** methods in **abstract** class are going to be executed  in a **subclass**. thank you for the answers.

Comment: What gets executed depends on the caller. Here caller is *Android* and calls `onCreate` method which is present in abstract class. Had derived class implemented it, it would've called derived class's onCreate method.